# How to register a type in the context of a request only with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a situation where I need to construct a type that depends on a string that needs to be passed to its constructor.

This string is only available after the user logs in to my application. So I have a block of code that basically on each start request, it registers the type if the user is authenticated.

```
container.RegisterType<IMyType, MyType>(new InjectionConstructor(stringParamenter));
```

It works as expected but only if no other user is using the website at the same time, because the `MyType` instance is overriden whenever a new user logs in with a new type with the new `stringParameter`.

So how can I register this type in a way that it will be available only for the current request?